# NSTimer Throwing Exception

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, nsexception

I'm currently struggling to implement even the simplest of timers into my project, since every one I try gives me this error log:

```
2015-12-19 14:23:47.164 Reanimate[14879:898570] -[Reanimate.helicut 

timerFunc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff95d29d3f0
2015-12-19 14:23:47.169 Reanimate[14879:898570] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Reanimate.helicut timerFunc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff95d29d3f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105dfef65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107e88deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e0758d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d54f7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d54b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x0000000106408671 __NSFireTimer + 83
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d5f364 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d5ef11 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1089
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d208b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1937
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d1fe98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bfc7ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106a11676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    12  Reanimate                           0x0000000105be62dd main + 109
    13  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108a1892d start + 1
    14  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is the code itself:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

var heli: SKSpriteNode?
var helibg1: SKSpriteNode?
var helibg2: SKSpriteNode?
weak var myTypeWriter: SKLabelNode?
var text = String()
var text2 = String()
var text3 = String()
var text4 = String()
var texty = String()
var myCounter = 0


class helicut: SKScene{
    var timer = NSTimer()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        heli = self.childNodeWithName("heli") as? SKSpriteNode
        helibg1 = self.childNodeWithName("helibg1") as? SKSpriteNode
        helibg2 = self.childNodeWithName("helibg2") as? SKSpriteNode
        myTypeWriter = self.childNodeWithName("type") as? SKLabelNode

        func timerr() {
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "timerFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
        func timerFunc() {
            print("it worked")
        }


        timerr()
```

As you can see the code is relatively simple, but even so I have no idea what could be causing the exception. I have tried using different selector syntax and messing around with just about everything, but I'm very stuck. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `timerr()` and `timerFunc()` out of `didMoveToView()`.

The function matching the `selector` must be defined on the top level of the class.

```
class helicut: SKScene {
  var timer = NSTimer()

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    heli = self.childNodeWithName("heli") as? SKSpriteNode
    helibg1 = self.childNodeWithName("helibg1") as? SKSpriteNode
    helibg2 = self.childNodeWithName("helibg2") as? SKSpriteNode
    myTypeWriter = self.childNodeWithName("type") as? SKLabelNode
    timerr()
  }

  func timerr() {
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "timerFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  }

  func timerFunc() {
    print("it worked")
  }
```